# rangeHighlights not showing with bootstrap-slider

Tags: bootstrap-slider

bootstrap-slider working, displays as intended, however the rangeHighlights do not seem to be appearing.

Copied the html/css/js code from http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider into my projects as it is on the site.

What am i doing wrong here?

```js
$('#ex22').slider({
  id: 'slider22',
  min: 0,
  max: 20,
  step: 1,
  value: 14,
  rangeHighlights: [{
      "start": 2,
      "end": 5,
      "class": "category1"
    },
    {
      "start": 7,
      "end": 8,
      "class": "category2"
    },
    {
      "start": 17,
      "end": 19
    },
    {
      "start": 17,
      "end": 24
    },
    {
      "start": -3,
      "end": 19
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#slider22 .slider-selection {
  background: #2196f3;
}

#slider22 .slider-rangeHighlight {
  background: #f70616;
}

#slider22 .slider-rangeHighlight.category1 {
  background: #FF9900;
}

#slider22 .slider-rangeHighlight.category2 {
  background: #99CC00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0036)http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/ -->
<html lang="en" style="" class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>



  <div id="example-22" class="slider-example">
    <input id="ex22" type="text" data-slider-id="slider22" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" data-slider-rangeHighlights='[{ "start": 2, "end": 5, "class": "category1" },
                                   { "start": 7, "end": 8, "class": "category2" },
                                   { "start": 17, "end": 19 },
                                   { "start": 17, "end": 24 }, //not visible -  out of slider range
                                   { "start": -3, "end": 19 }]' />
  </div>


  <script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you use bootstrap 4. For now it won't work with this version. Use bootstrap 3 or you have to adjust bootstrap-slider to new bootstrap.